# Mockito Repetitive Method Call on the same Funciton/Constructor being Tested

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Here is class `Person`

```
public class Person {
    // ...
    public String getInfo(String key)
            return key; //for brevity
    }
}
```

And another class `Student` having a dependency on `Person` (Note that the current implementation is part of the problem and we cannot modify these two classes)

```
public class Student {
    private String copyFirstName;
    private String otherInfo;

    private Person person;
    Student(Person p) {
        person = p;

        copyFirstName = person.getInfo("firstName")

        if (copyFirstName == null || copyFirstName.equals("")) { //entry point A
            throw new SomethingError("message here");
        }

        otherInfo = person.getInfo("bio")

        if (otherInfo == null || otherInfo.equals("")) { // entry point B
            throw new SomethingError("message here");
        }
    }
}
```

The classes above may look impractical but take it as part of the problem that we cannot change.

The goal is to have a complete coverage of all lines in testing. To do this, I plan to make two tests to cover the two `if` statements and mock the method `getInfo` while noting what parameter is passed so that I know when to skip the "entry point A" for the second test of the constructor.

Ideally this would be my JUnit Class

```
public class StudentTest {
    private Person person;
    private Student student;
    private Person mockedPerson;

    @Before
    public void init()
    throws SomethingError  {
        person = new Person();
        student = new Student();
        mockedPerson = Mockito.mock(Person.class);
    }

    @Test(expected=SomethingError.class)
    public void myTest1()
    throws SomethingError {
        Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("firstName"))
        .thenAnswer(
            new Answer<String>(){
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                String arg = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
                System.out.println(arg);
                if (arg.equals("firstName")) {
                    return null;
                }
                return person.getInfo(arg); // default value
            }});

        try {
            new Student(mockedPerson);
            fail();
        } catch (MultilingualException e) {
            Mockito.reset(mockedPerson); // not sure if this works
            assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "message here");
        }
    }

    @Test(expected=SomethingError.class)
    public void myTest2()
    throws SomethingError {
        Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("bio"))
        .thenAnswer(
            new Answer<String>(){
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                String arg = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
                System.out.println(arg);
                if (arg.equals("bio")) {
                    return "";
                }
                return person.getInfo(arg); // defaul value for firstName
            }});

        try {
            new Student(mockedPerson);
            fail();
        } catch (MultilingualException e) {
            Mockito.reset(mockedPerson); // not sure if this works
            assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "message here");
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. `myTest1` successfully entered the first `if` statement. But then on `myTest2`, the second `if` statement is missed. Strangely everything below @Override of `myTest2` is missed and immediately goes into its `catch`.

I also tried creating individual mocked instance of `Person` but it still has an identical coverage result.

How would you test and cover the two consecutive `if` statements in the constructor that gets the evaluated value from the same method?

**Edit**

I did try the simplest method below but it seems that `.when` does not care of what the value of the argument is since the second test still triggers the first `if`.

```
@Test(expected=SomethingError.class)
public void test() throws SomethingError {
    Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("firstName")).thenReturn(null);
    try {
        new Student(mockedPerson);
    } catch (SomethingError e) {
        assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "message here");
    }
}

@Test(expected=SomethingError.class)
public void test2() throws SomethingError {
    Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("bio")).thenReturn(null);
    try {
        new Student(mockedPerson);
    } catch (SomethingError e) {
        assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "message here");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any value in testing an object like this using Mockito.  It proves nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for that `private Student student;`, actualy you can get rid of all those fields in your test class, your tests sould be as independent as possible, and in your case you could do the mocking and stubing alltoghether in each test method. 
Use

```
ArgumentMatchers.eq("firstName");
```

to check you argument value equality, You may also use the answer variant if you want, but in you case this is much simpler.

Here is how your tests could look like:

```
@Test
public void newStudentWithPersonWithNullFirstName() {

    Person person = Mockito.mock(Person.class);

    Mockito
        .doReturn(null)
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("firstName"));

    SomethingError actual = Assert
            .assertThrows(SomethingError.class, () -> new Student(person));
    Assert.assertEquals("firstName is null or empty", actual.getMessage());
}

@Test
public void newStudentWithPersonWithEmptyFirstName() {

    Person person = Mockito.mock(Person.class);

    Mockito
        .doReturn("")
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("firstName"));

    SomethingError actual = Assert
            .assertThrows(SomethingError.class, () -> new Student(person));
    Assert.assertEquals("firstName is null or empty", actual.getMessage());
}

@Test
public void newStudentWithPersonWithNullBio() {

    Person person = Mockito.mock(Person.class);

    Mockito
        .doReturn("Foo")
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("firstName"));

    Mockito
        .doReturn(null)
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("bio"));

    SomethingError actual = Assert
            .assertThrows(SomethingError.class, () -> new Student(person));
    Assert.assertEquals("bio is null or empty", actual.getMessage());
}

@Test
public void newStudentWithPersonWithEmptyBio() {

    Person person = Mockito.mock(Person.class);

    Mockito
        .doReturn("Foo")
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("firstName"));

    Mockito
        .doReturn("")
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("bio"));

    SomethingError actual = Assert
            .assertThrows(SomethingError.class, () -> new Student(person));
    Assert.assertEquals("bio is null or empty", actual.getMessage());
}

@Test
public void newStudentWithPersonSuccess() {

    Person person = Mockito.mock(Person.class);

    Mockito
        .doReturn("Foo")
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("firstName"));

    Mockito
        .doReturn("Bar")
        .when(person)
        .getInfo(ArgumentMatchers.eq("bio"));

    Student actual = new Student(person);
    Assert.assertEquals("Foo", actual.getCopyFirstName());
    Assert.assertEquals("Bar", actual.getOtherInfo());
}
```

Coverage:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't seem to find the the import for `ArgumentMatchers`? Where is this from

Comment: @ColdCerberus This if from [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html), use your IDE to get suggestions for missing imports (for eclipse it is Ctrl+Shift+o)

Comment: So I tried what you have given but replaced that part with `Mockito
        .doReturn(null)
        .when(person)
        .getInfo("firstName");`

we are not using mockito core but  mockito-all-1.10.19

Comment: @ColdCerberus [mockito-all-1.10.19](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19) that's nearly a decade (is you round up) old, is there any chane you can use a more recent version of mockito? otherewise you will need to figure out how to implement that check with whatever that version provides.

Comment: Ok for some reason it worked when I made a new class and did what you have shown but without the `ArgumentMatchers`. And it worked. will mark this as correct answer .

Comment: @ColdCerberus glad you could make it work! btw. you could also use `doAnswer` and return a valid firstname if the first argument is equal to `"firstName"` otherweise `null`, the same goes for `"bio"`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you also need to mock the `Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("firstName"))` for your second unit test.
You 'omitted' the code of `getInfo` for brevity but I feel like it is returning null/empty and hence, throwing the exception for the first if check.

Looking at your code, doing a simple:

```
Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("firstName"))
.thenReturn("");
```

might work.

Comment: I made sure that `getInfo` does not return `null` or `""`. I did use `.thenReturn("");` the same way you did, but it actually didn't care about the passed value `"firstName"`. It still works with whatever value you put. Example: `Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("lkasjdl")).thenReturn("");` still works. So I can't use this to skip the first `if` statement the second time I test the constructor for the second `if`.

Comment: So, based on your edit you are still missing what I meant.
What about this adding `Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("firstName")).thenReturn("anything but empty or null");` before yours `Mockito.when(mockedPerson.getInfo("bio")).thenReturn(null);`?

Comment: It will only come in the the first if statement since the second time it goes back to the constructor on the `test2`, `"firstName"` is still mocked to return null. So I have to make it separately where the first test should also reset or remove the mock so that we can go to the next `if` the second time.